# Using tcpdump to capture a specific port when UDP message can be fragmented

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I am running tcpdump to capture UDP messages on a specific port. The UDP traffic being captured contains fragmented UDP packets.

When a fragmented UDP packet is encountered, tcpdump is only capturing the first fragment. (Probably because only the first fragment contains the port information).

Is there a switch on TCP dump that will capture all the fragments of a UDP packet even when messages from a port are being filtered?

Comment: I think you would need to add a clause in your filter to capture all fragmented IP packets, then use a tool like wireshark that can re-assemble the IP packets for you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the reassembled UDP stream?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I think what you mean is how to extend the snaplen as you're only catching a snippet of the packet with tcpdump. The default snaplen is usually 68 bytes.

Setting snaplen to 0 sets it to the default of 65535 bytes so run tcpdump with "-s 0" to capture everything. Are you running with the '-s' switch?

It's recommended that you limit snaplen to the smallest number that will capture the protocol information you're interested in.

HTH!